# Lock pdf using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I recently tried to move to iText7, but I have some issues. I already have a PDF and I am trying to lock and restrict permissions on this PDF. I used the same approach with itext5, but the result is not the same. To be more precise:

1. I used

   ```
   PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fos, new WriterProperties()
           .setPublicKeyEncryption(chain,
           new int[EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_DEGRADED_PRINTING],
           EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_256));
   ```

but nothing happened, then I tried

2.

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fos, new WriterProperties()
            .setStandardEncryption("lala".getBytes(), "lala".getBytes(),
             EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING | EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_256,
                    EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_256));
```

nothing happened again. Do you happen to know something about it ?

Full code of the method:

```
 public void signPDF(InputStream inputStream, HttpServletResponse response) {
        LOG.debug("Inside signPDF...");
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        try(OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(os, new WriterProperties().setStandardEncryption(null, "test".getBytes(), EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                    EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | EncryptionConstants.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA))) {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream(p12Path), keystorePassword.toCharArray());
            String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
            PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
            Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
            BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
            ITSAClient tsc = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaClient, "", "");
            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, writer.getOutputStream(), true);
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance()
                    .setReason("Sign")
                    .setLocation("Test")
                    .setReuseAppearance(false);
            signer.setFieldName("sig");
            IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName());
            IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            System.out.println(signer.getDocument().getNumberOfPages());
            addWatermark(appearance,signer);
            signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, null, tsc, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error while writing to outputstream",e);
        }
    }
```

Now it is signed, it has watermark, but it is not locked (i.e to copy the content)

Comment: Please show us the full version of the code. The writer creation logic you use is correct and should produce the password-encrypted document.

Comment: Ah, so you want to both sign and encrypt, and the way you combine those two tasks is wrong, your `PdfWriter` with the encryption information is not used at all. I'll try and correct the code later.

Comment: Thanks @mkl I had the code written for version 5.x and now I changed it to 7.x and I found it a bit tricky.

Comment: Note that PdfEncryptor.encrypt() closes the stream....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signing and encryption in iText 7 currently is done in two separate steps, in the first step the file is encrypted and in the second step this encrypted file is signed keeping encryption intact.

In your attempt you created a `PdfWriter` with the encryption information and a `PdfSigner` with the signing information. As your `PdfWriter` is not used by any `PdfDocument`, though, the encryption information are lost, only the signing takes place.

To both encrypt and sign, simply first encrypt the PDF, e.g. using something like

```java
void encrypt(InputStream source, OutputStream target, byte[] password) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(target, new WriterProperties().setStandardEncryption(null, password,
            EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING, EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | EncryptionConstants.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA));
    new PdfDocument(reader, writer).close();
}
```

*(an [EncryptAndSign](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/EncryptAndSign.java#L87) method)*

and then sign this encrypted PDF, e.g. using something like

```
void sign(InputStream original, OutputStream result, String name, CryptoStandard subfilter,
        int certificationLevel, boolean isAppendMode, byte[] password) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    String reason = "Just another illusionary reason";
    String location = "Right around the corner";
    boolean setReuseAppearance = false;
    String digestAlgorithm = "SHA512";
    ITSAClient tsc = null;

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(original, new ReaderProperties().setPassword(password));
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, result, isAppendMode);

    signer.setCertificationLevel(certificationLevel);

    // Creating the appearance
    signer.getSignatureAppearance()
          .setReason(reason)
          .setLocation(location)
          .setReuseAppearance(setReuseAppearance);

    signer.setFieldName(name);

    // Creating the signature
    IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    signer.signDetached(new BouncyCastleDigest(), pks, chain, null, null, tsc, 0, subfilter);
}
```

*(an [EncryptAndSign](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/EncryptAndSign.java#L95) method)*

with `pk` and `chain` determined like in your code.

Then combine these methods, e.g. like this

```
try (   InputStream resourceStream = ...;
        OutputStream encryptedResult = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile)  ) {
    encrypt(resourceStream, encryptedResult, password);
}

try (   InputStream encryptedSource = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);
        OutputStream signedResult = new FileOutputStream(signedFile)) {
    sign(encryptedSource, signedResult, "Signature", CryptoStandard.CADES, 0, false, password);
}
```

*([EncryptAndSign](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/EncryptAndSign.java#L70) test `testEncryptAndSignLefterisBab`)*

or if you want to write to a Response and don't want intermediary files in the file system:

```
byte[] encrypted = null;

try (   InputStream resourceStream = ...;
        OutputStream encryptedResult = new ByteArrayOutputStream()  ) {
    encrypt(resourceStream, encryptedResult, password);
    encrypted = encryptedResult.toByteArray();
}

try (   InputStream encryptedSource = new ByteArrayInputStream(encrypted);
        OutputStream signedResult = response.getOutputStream()   ) {
    sign(encryptedSource, signedResult, "Signature", CryptoStandard.CADES, 0, false, password);
}
```